# How to distribute entries in the table in view in decreasing order among subjects from a to z (a,b,c,d,e,f,g etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to distribute entries in the table in view in decreasing order among subjects from a to z (a,b,c,d,e,f,g etc). For example, the subject, which name English has to be ahead of the subject, which name French or German. And a subject chemistry, for example, ahead of all.

Answer (score 0):

To start with - give proper variable names. WTF is @a?! Teachers list? Really?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

```
@subjects = Subject.order(:name).all
```

And you probably want to replace 'Subject' by 'Course'.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you spend a bit of time familiarizing yourself with the conventions used within Rails applications. Also, ensure you have properly defined your relationships within your models so that you can use the full power of ActiveRecord. I'm making a guess at your relationships, but I'm guessing this is a pretty accurate representation:

```
+------------+               +-----------------+             +------------+
|  Teachers  |-|-----------|<|  Subscriptions  |>|---------|-|  Subjects  |
+------------+               +-----------------+             +------------+
```

**Models**

```
# app/models/subject.rb
class Subject
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :teachers, through: :subscriptions
end

# app/models/teacher.rb
class Teacher
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subjects, through: :subscriptions

  def display_name
    "#{self.surname} #{self.name}"
  end
end

# app/models/subscription.rb
class Subscription
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

**Controller**

```
# app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb

class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @subscriptions = Subscription.includes(:teacher, :subject).order("courses.name ASC").all
    end
 end
```

**View**

```
# app/views/subscriptions/index.html.erb
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Teacher</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= content_tag_for :tr, @subscriptions do |subscription| %>
      <td><%= subscription.subject.name %></td>
      <td><%= subscription.teacher.display_name %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```